# An abundance of ternary operators

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to find a way to do what this method does in a cleaner, less hacky looking way

```
 def self.create_from_person!(person)
    spi = new(:person => person, :provider => person.provider)
    spi.age_eligible_code = participant.age_eligible?(person) ? 1 : 2
    spi.county_of_residence_code = participant.psu_county_eligible?(person) ? 1 : 2
    spi.first_prenatal_visit_code = participant.first_visit?(person) ? 1 : 2
    spi.pregnancy_eligible_code = participant.pbs_pregnant?(person) ? 1 : 2
    spi.save!
  end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: where does `participant` come from?

Comment: @tokland `participant` is from a different model. I have some doubt that the eligibility methods belong there instead of on `Person` but thats not directly related to the feature I am working on. In case your interested the `Participant` model and the rest of the project is [here](https://github.com/NUBIC/ncs_navigator_core/blob/master/app/models/participant.rb) I like the refactoring below and I'm thinking about submitting it as part of my commit, if thats okay with you

Comment: It's ok, of course. But I still don't see where is `participant` defined. To be called from a classmethod it should be a classmethod as well, but with that name it doesn't look like one.

Comment: ah, right. its a bug with my implementation from above. Its defined as an association on person so there should be a line above that is like `participant = person.participant`. Thanks.

Comment: ok! that's what it seemed, a local variable yet to be defined.

Comment: What model is this method in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notes:

- Any reason not to set the attributes in a single `create` step?
- DRY by using procs for short-lived functions.
- Methods should return meaningful values. Here it makes sense to return the newly created object.
- (As Mark pointed out) The mismatch names between attributes makes the code more verbose that it should be. However, I guess part of this mismatch already comes from the app you are patching.
- `:provider => person.provider`. Note that this can break referential integrity. Person may change its provider in the future, but this model will remain as it is.

I'd write:

```
def self.create_from_person!(person)
  code = lambda { |value| value ? 1 : 2 }
  create!({
    :person => person, 
    :provider => person.provider,
    :age_eligible_code => code[participant.age_eligible?(person)],
    :county_of_residence_code => code[participant.psu_county_eligible?(person)],
    :first_prenatal_visit_code => code[participant.first_visit?(person)],
    :pregnancy_eligible_code => code[participant.pbs_pregnant?(person)],
  })
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesn't look clean is because the underlying models are inconsistent.

In one, you return a boolean true/false for `age_eligible?` and in another, you call it `age_eligible_code` and store a 1 for true and 2 for false. If these were aligned such that they were both boolean values, you wouldn't need any ternary operators at all.

Comment: Indeed, also the ":provider => person.provider" may create inconsistencies in the SQL tables.